# Count Number of Words existed in Word Document

Tags: jquery, word, openxml

Hello Group members,
                    I have a document,Where When I upload the document in document library or in List then I need to count the total number of words existed in Word Document Library and put is list item .I am using Jquery Can you tell me how can I get total number of word existed in Word Document.Hope some one will help me to solve this problem.

Thanks,
http://siddiq-sharepoint2010.blogspot.com
MOHAMMAD SIDDIQALI.

Answer (score 4):

You need to do server side processing of this. Cannot be done in any (decent) way using client script (JavaScript). I suggest you move this feature to an Event Receiver and use the OpenXML SDK to count the words.